# Weekday Values Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that I am writing a script for. My newest section of a macro code is supposed to fill column F with a weekday numerical value based off of column B which has values of date and time (MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss). Once I added the section to the end of the macro code, it comes back with the Error Code "Exception: AutoFill destination range must extend the source range in only one direction." The code will add the value, but it doesn't correctly correspond to most days.

```
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=WEEKDAY(B2, 1)');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('F:F'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F:F').activate();
```

Comment: You should avoid using ranges like `F:F` because they tend to return nulls between `sh.getLastRow() and sh.getMaxRows()`.  You can use like this: `sh.getRange('F:F').filter(r=>r[0]!='');`

Comment: Hi there @blackgold! Please test the approach commented by @MetaMan and write back sharing your results.

Comment: @MetaMan still new to Java, thank you for the input. Unfortunately, putting the fix in line 2 and/or 3 still resulted in error messages and did not accurately assign values to the day. Could it be a possibility of column B having the time in it as well? When I manually add the function in, it is accurate, but have had trouble scripting it.

Comment: Update: Got it to work

Comment: The programming language used in the Google Apps Script IDE is JavaScript not Java. P.S. If you think that the solution that you found might be helpful to others, please post it as an answer, otherwise consider delete this question.